# Infinispan command dispatcher problem if multiple applications are deployed on Wildfly 13 EE8

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, infinispan, java-ee-8

I do have a problem with my newly obtained infrastructure and maybe someone can point out for me what's wrong or where to look at.

I have multiple applications (packed as war's, I tried ear's too) using the same backend-jar's (business/service jars and entity containing jar)

something like that:

```
app1.war    
/WEB-INF/lib/  
|--app1-logik.jar    
|--common-business-logik.jar  
|--common-entity-mappings.jar

app2.war  
/WEB-INF/lib/  
|--app2-logik.jar  
|--common-business-logik.jar  
|--common-entity-mappings.jar
```

For our deployment strategy, it is not possible to pack the common parts into a separate deployment. So I have to stick with this. It looks like there is only a problem with the stateful beans annotated with 
`@Stateful @Named @SessionScoped @Clustered`.
These are most likely located in common-business-logik.jar

The problem occurs during the second deployment process (the first one is working as expected).

> Thrown in org.wildfly.clustering.server.dispatcher.MangedCommandDispatcherFactory.cre>ateCommandDispatcher(Object id, C context) line 98
>   "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"app2.ear\".\"app2.war\".component.StatefullBean.START" => "java.lang.Ille
>   galArgumentException: WFLYCLSV0017: A command dispatcher for StatefullBean already exists, but with a different command context                slave1           | [Server:group1]     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYCLSV0017: A command dispatcher for StatefullBean alrea
>   dy exists, but with a different command context",
>   slave1           | [Server:group1]         "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"app2.ear\".\"app2.war\".component.StatefulBean2.START" => "java.lang.IllegalA
>   rgumentException: WFLYCLSV0017: A command dispatcher for StatefulBean2 already exists, but with a different command context                        slave1           | [Server:group1]     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYCLSV0017: A command dispatcher for StatefulBean2 already e
>   xists, but with a different command context"
>   slave1           | [Server:group1]     },
>   slave1           | [Server:group1]     "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
>   slave1           | [Server:group1]         "Services that were unable to start:" => [                                                                          slave1           | [Server:group1]             "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"app2.ear\".\"app2.war\".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart",
>   slave1           | [Server:group1]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"app2.ear\".WeldEndInitService",                                                        slave1           | [Server:group1]             "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./app2"
>   slave1           | [Server:group1]         ],                                                                                                                  slave1           | [Server:group1]         "Services that may be the cause:" => 
>   `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug.  I've just filed:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-11088
and will submit a fix momentarily.